# Spark - how to get all relevant columns based on ambiguous names

Tags: python, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have are several dataframes as below. The goal is to find all the relevant information using `product_name` as keys. The problem is, sometimes it is called `prod_name` or other similar names. Also for example if `product_name` is linked to `ser_no`, the information in that data frame belongs to this product as well. Examples as below, let me know if I can explain this better.

Could someone please help to shed some light on this? I am trying to automate this process with out explicitly joining them together, as there are many tables like this, and I do not know all the exact table/col names. Basically I am trying to pull out all the info relevant to a `product_name` from these hive tables. It feels like `connectedComponent` In Spark graphX api but not quite? Many thanks for your help.

df1:

```
prod_name    value 
    A      code1
    B      code2
    C      code3, code 33
    D       code4
```

df2:

```
product_name.    jvalue 
  A            indi3
  B            indi4
  C            indi5
  D            indi6
```

df3:

```
   product_name.    ser_no 
     A               100
     B               200
     C               300
     D               400
```

df4:

```
  colour.         ser_no 
  Amber           100
  Blue            200
  Orange          300
  Green           400
```

expected output:

```
product_no    value          jvalue     ser_no   colour 
    A        code1.           indi3.     100.     Amber
    B        code2            indi4.     200      Blue
    C        code3, code 33.  indi5      300      Orange
    D        code4            indi6      400      Green
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there are 3 parts to your question.

1. Discovering all the tables that have the same logical column, even when the exact column names differ.
2. Discovering all [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) across a set of DataFrames.
3. Joining a collection of DataFrames together based on appropriate join keys, even when the join key is under a different column name for each DataFrame.

#### Sub-problem 1

First we will need a method to check if a column name matches our logical column. We will use this as a filter.
A regex would be a reasonable approach, but in this case I will simply enumerate a set column names that should be treated the same.

```scala
val productNameColumns = Seq("prod_name", "product_name", "product")
```

Since you have mentioned Hive, I will assume we can use the Spark Catalog to discover tables. We can grab all columns, in all tables, that match our logical column using code like the following.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit}

val allTables = spark.catalog.listTables().select("name").as[String].collect

val tableColumns = allTables
    .map { tableName => 
        // If you have many tables, this will start many spark jobs. This may be too slow to be feasible.
        spark.catalog
            .listColumns(tableName)
            .where(col("name").isin(productNameColumns: _*))
            // or `.where(col("name").rlike(some-regex))` if using a regex
            .select(
                lit(tableName).as("table"),
                col("name").as("column")
            )
            // Make sure that we only take 1 column per table. This may not be needed depending on your data.
            .groupBy("table")
            .agg(
                first(col("column")).as("column")
            )
    }
    .reduce(_ union _)
    .as[(String, String)]
    .collect
    .toMap
```

The above code assumes you only care about the current database. You could iterate over all databases if you need wanted.

The `tableColumns` map is the answer to sub-problem 1. The keys are the table names and the values are the columns names that correspond to "product name".

#### Sub-problem 2

Sub-problem 2 is a classic example of foreign key discovery. This is an entire research field in itself. [I suggest](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-21042-1_37) you [do some reading](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.222.7732)
on [this subject](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221035501_A_Machine_Learning_Approach_to_Foreign_Key_Discovery) before going down this road. It may seem simple, but it is deceptively difficult. This is especially true when we
start talking about keys that are made up of multiple columns.

Let's set this feature aside and move on to sub-problem 3.

#### Sub-problem 3

The easiest solution to sub-problem 3 is to standardize the column names you will join on. This is easy because we already know the column
names for each DataFrame after solving sub-problem 1. We can iterate over our map and rename the column we will join on and then reduce a join.

I have assumed a `"full_outer"` join because that way we won't lose information about any record. Of course, no matter what join type you pick
there will potentially be an explosion of rows if the join key isn't a primary key (unique across rows) for all DataFrames. This will likely
be an expensive DataFrame to create regardless.

```scala
tableColumns
    .map { case (tableName, columnName) =>
        spark.table(tableName).withColumnRenamed(columnName, "__join_column")
    }
    .reduce { case (accDf, nextDf) =>
        accDf.join(nextDf, Seq("__join_column"), "full_outer")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I got an error running the sample "type mismatch : found: ....catalog.Column] required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] " Can you tell where the problem is?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about which part of the code throws the error? I just fixed one typo in my code. The `flatMap` should have been `map`.